# My HTML Button is not running in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Ok So i'm doing my GCSE Coursework and I've came across a problem with my script

The problem is my button for the script will not work with JavaScript

Here's the script;

```
</head>
<h1>Traffic Light Sequence</h1>

<img id="Red.jpg" src="Red.jpg">

<button type="button" onclick="changeLights()">Change Lights</button>

<script>
var list=["Red.jpg","Amber.jpg","Green.jpg","Amber.jpg"]

var count:0,1

function changeLights() {
var image = document.getElementById('Red.jpg');
if list=0 {
    image.src=list[0];
if list=1 {
    image.src=list[1];
} else if list=2 {
    image.src=list[2];
} else > 3 {
    image.src=list[3];
}

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have clearly made the button, created an onClick, and opened a function with it

Comment: The syntax error in the function might prevent it from working. Did you look at the error console of your browser?

Comment: No Gerald But thanks for the tip ill have a look

Comment: Surely your javascript console has told you that you have missing semicolons, `count` set as an object even though it's not, weird if statements etc.

Comment: Waqit this is your GCSE coursework? Damn..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a quick glance there are quite a few things wrong here...

- You don't need `javascript:` in the `onclick` attribute
- You forgot the semi-colon after declaring the `list` variable
- I don't know *what* this even is: `var count:0,1` other than a syntax error.  Maybe you meant `var count = 0;` ?  (Also forgot the semi-colon there.)  But you never *use* this variable, so you don't even need it.
- You forgot the semi-colon here: `document.addEventListener("click")`, but you don't even *need* this line of code at all because it isn't doing anything.
- The `if` conditions need parentheses and need to use `==` (equality) instead of `=` (assignment): `if (list==0)`
- You forgot the closing `}` after the first `if` block.
- This is a syntax error: `else > 3`  An `else` is just an `else`, there is no condition that does with it.
- Additionally, what are you even checking in those `if` conditions?  A list will never equal an integer.  I'm not even really sure what to suggest here.  In plain English, what are you *asking* that `if` to check?

There may be more that I missed...

Comment: And lastly, `if (array === 1)` will never ever be true and `if (array == 1)` will give the wrong result. I think OP also needs a `currentIndex` variable.

Comment: @h2ooooooo: Good catch.  I'm not even really sure what the OP is *trying* to check in those conditionals.  Maybe he wants to examine the current state of `img.src` against the string values in the list instead?

Comment: Without knowing it I think he's trying to use a typical "first click = first item, second click = second item, third click = third item, if the end of the array is reached reset index to 0" so every time you'd click the stoplight it'd change state. That would also explain the "amber" part being there twice (it seems he's trying to yoyo the iteration by going 0, 1, 2, 1, 0 etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this code (https://jsfiddle.net/6d3tkm6y/):

```
<h1>Traffic Light Sequence</h1>

<img id="Red.jpg" src="Red.jpg">

<h2 id="display">Red</h2>

<button type="button" onclick="changeLights()">Change Lights</button>

<script>
  var list=["Red.jpg","Amber.jpg","Green.jpg","Amber.jpg"];
  var index = 0;

  function changeLights() {
    var image = document.getElementById('Red.jpg');
    var display = document.getElementById('display');
    index = (index + 1) % 4;
    image.src = list[index];
    display.innerHTML = list[index];

  }
</script>
```

The `display` element in my code is only there so you can see what is happening with the light, since I don't have the image files you're using.

You don't need any of the `if..else if` statements. You can just use an `index` to loop over your array. The `% 4` automatically wraps your index around once it hits four (So you just need to increase it by one). This way your function is essentially reduced to just 3 lines.

Also, you should definitely look a bit more into some general javascript syntax ;)

Comment: Thanks for this @Keiwan  may i ask  what the display.innetHTML tag means

Comment: No problem. That changes the Text inside the <h2> element.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a great number of syntax and logic errors.
Regardless, here it is corrected, plus text field.

```
<h3>Traffic Light Sequence</h3>

<img id="Red.jpg" src="Red.jpg">
<div id="example">
  Red.jpg
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="changeLights()">Change Lights</button>

<script>
  var list = ["Red.jpg", "Amber.jpg", "Green.jpg", "Amber.jpg"]
  var count = 0;
  function changeLights() {
    count+=1;
    if(count==4)
      count = 0;
    var image = document.getElementById('Red.jpg');
    image.src = list[count];
    //extra code because I don't have images
    var example = document.getElementById('example');
    example.innerHTML = list[count];
  }
</script>
```

[Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/tq2wb7nv/)